# Input CSV in lightning component and pass to Apex controller

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning

I need to input a CSV file using `<input type='file'>` from an Lightning Component and pass it to an Apex Controller for further processing.

**Component**

```
<input type="file"  aura:id="file-upload-input" id="file-upload" class="slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text" onchange="{!c.fileSelected}"/>
```

**JS Controller**

```
fileSelected : function(component, event, helper) {
    var fileInput = component.find("file-upload-input").getElement();
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    console.log('file'+file);
    var action = component.get("c.passFile");
    action.setParams({ file : file } );

    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        console.log((actionResult.getReturnValue()));
        // component.set("v.emailStr", actionResult.getReturnValue());     
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

**Apex Controller**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void passFile(Blob file)
{
    System.debug('Inside Apex');
    System.debug('file'+file);
}
```

This gives an Salesforce Internal Error

Answer (score 7):

You can't pass a `Blob` type to an apex controller method. You'll have to encode the file in your Javascript method, then decode it in your apex controller like this:

**Lightning controller**

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var self = this;
reader.onload = function () {
     action.setParams({ file : encodeURIComponent(reader.result) } );
     action.setCallback(self, function(actionResult) {
         console.log((actionResult.getReturnValue()));
         // component.set("v.emailStr", actionResult.getReturnValue());     
     });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

**Apex controller**

```
String myFile = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(file, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Why the delete?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Because I was missing a part :)